# Choosing accelerometer or displacement sensor for system

Tags: sensor, control, control-system, feedback, pid-controller

I am working on an electro-servo motor system which can be seen as a similar in [here](http://www.quanser.com/products/shake_table_II)! It is a shaketable system which converts acceleration input to displacement output. My question involves a bit theory; what kind of sensor should be use on these systems for feedback? Accelerometer or displacement sensor as LVDT? Question is totally based on sensor specifications but if we assume all specifications are same, is there any advantages to use an accelerometer instead of LVDT. In my opinion it is pretty sensible to use an accelerometer for feedback but i can not sure. I want to know your opinion.

Answer (score 1):

You will need some displacement sensing for sure, otherwise the bias error will accumulate and your table will eventually slam into the end stops.

I would suggest looking at displacement feedback via an encoder on the servomotor and monitoring with an accelerometer if desired/required. If you are using a commercial control system you may be feeding it a displacement signal directly. Of course the servo will have limitations in force (acceleration) as well as slew rate and you will want to filter and pre-process the file before sending it through to the actuator(s).

Fortunately the kinematics for this setup are simple (as opposed to, say, a hexapod) so it should not be too hard to compute.

Answer (score 0):

Shake tables need accelerometers, since these can be used as feedback to control the force exerted on the test article (or, equivalently, acceleration), and to determine response and resonances. If all you control is displacement, it's entirely possible to break the sturdiest component.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, could you explain a little more? Or if you dont mind could you send me a paper or study for this? I excatly need its math.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, the specs are not the same.  Further, you can get acceleration from displacement and displacement from acceleration.  That said, accelerometers are dirt cheap,  and don't require the level of signal processing that LVDT's do.  I'd go with an accelerometer, and if you need displacement as well (or instead), I recommend running through the specs to see if a ratiometric Hall effect sensor might be good enough.

Answer (score 0):

You would need a linear displacement sensor, like optic scale,etc..or an encoder mounted on a motor shaft (motor with encoder). Without it you can't position the table.
The extra sensor is an accelerometer, to have a trace of acceleration/shakes.